# What is the actual number or calculation for the Connect API Rate Limit

Tags: rest-api, connect-api

I'm in the process of designing something that will use the Connect REST API and am not able to find any documentation on what the actual number of calls is limited to or how to calculate them. I understand it is a per user, per application, per hour limit, but what I cannot find is what the actual limit is.

The [Connect REST API Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_chatter_rest.htm) documentation has:

> Connect REST API requests are subject to rate limiting. Connect REST API has a different rate limit than other Salesforce APIs. Connect REST API has a per user, per application, per hour rate limit. When you exceed the rate limit, all Connect REST API resources return a 503 Service Unavailable error code.

> For applications using a session ID from Salesforce, the rate limit is per user, per hour—there isn't a separate bucket for applications.

The [API Request Limits and Allocations page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm) does not have anything about the Connect API other than to state that you should refer to the Connect API docs, which don't have an actual number.

My question is what is the actual number that is the Connect REST API per user, per application, per hour limit or how can I calculate it?

Comment: any luck i am looking for same?

Comment: @Harshi - Yes. I just posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I opened a case with Salesforce support to get more information and the response is that it may differ based on what APIs are being called and to talk to your Salesforce AE about pricing and limits around the APIs you need within the Connect API.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link : https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000381578&type=1

> Login requests exceeding 3,600 requests per hour per user will be blocked, and the LOGIN_RATE_EXCEEDED error will be captured in the org's

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of that limit, but I'm looking for a specified limit on the Connect REST API. Do you have that? I did not see that in the linked to article.